# Use the substitution $A_n=r^n$ to solve each of the recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Use the substitution $A_n=r^n$ to solve each of the recurrence relation:

(a)$2A_n=7A_{n-1}-3A_{n-2}; n \ge 0;A_0=A_1=1$

(b)$2S_n=7S_{n-1}-3S_{n-2}; n \ge 0;S_0=S_1=1$

This is a problem in my study guide and (a) and (b) seems the same problem to me. We can solve (a) by letting $A=r^n$ and we can solve (b) by letting $S=t^n$ or something. Both (a) & (b) should have the same solution. I am a bit perplexed why the professor will put the same problem twice.
Am I missing something?

Comment: 99% chance it's a typo. But if you're "perplexed why the professor will put the same problem twice," why don't you *ask the professor*?

Comment: `n ≥ 0` That should rather be $\,n \ge \color{red}{2}\,$. Other than that, yes, it's the same problem.

Comment: also i think it must be $$A_n=r^n$$

Comment: Yes ineed they seems the same problem, that's good you can solve only one!

Comment: The professor who set up the study guide is on sabbatical and he will return next month. So, have to wait till then to ask him the question. Meanwhile, I need to study for my comprehensive exam, so reaching out here to see if anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: @nova_star are you aware how proceed to solve it?

Comment: @gimusi, yes I was able to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: @nova_star You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: with your Substitution we get $$2q^n=7q^{n-1}-3q^{n-2}$$
this gives the solution $$a_n=\frac{1}{5}2^{-n}(4+6^n)$$
which is the same as your result.

Comment: Solving for it, I got $A_n=1/5(2^{2-n}+3^n)$